# disk mount: what does "require additional authorization to mount" do?

Tags: 16.04, mount, hard-drive

In ubunutu 16.04, I am exploring an external HDD with the utility **Disks**.  Under the **mount options** interface, I see the possibility to *require additional authorization to mount*.

[image]

I selected the option and all it did was to add `x-udisks-auth` to `nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto`. I couldn't find any relevant information about the above option, and a search on `x-udisks-auth` led me to unintelligible information for my limited understanding of file systems and disks.

So: simply put, what kind of additional authorization is required when choosing the above mentioned option? And I'd welcome some entry level explanation on the signification of `x-udisks-auth`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the [`udisks` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/udisks.8.html) does a fairly good job of explaining this:

```
ACCESS CONTROL
   By default, logged-in users in active log-in sessions are permitted to
   perform operations (for example, mounting, unlocking or modifying) on
   devices attached to the seat their session is on. Access-control is
   fine-grained and based on polkit(8), see the “Authorization Checks”
   chapter in the udisks documentation for more information. Note that the
   x-udisks-auth option can be used in the /etc/fstab and /etc/crypttab
   files to specify that additional authorization is required to mount
   resp. unlock the device (typically requiring the user to authenticate
   as an administrator).
```

So, by default, a user who is locally logged in (and not remotely, say via SSH, etc.) can plug in a USB disk and mount it without having to authenticate as the administrator. The `x-udisks-auth` disables this and forces you to provide authorization.

Authorization will be done via polkit, as it says. So you will have to authenticate as a user who has rights to the Polkit actions corresponding to mounting, unmounting, ejecting, etc. By default, those will be administrator users (those belonging to the `sudo` group).

If you are an administrator, you just have to provide your password:

[image]

In the image, the Polkit action is `org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-fstab`.

If other administrator users are also present on the system, you'll be able to select which user to authenticate as.

Comment: It seems clear to me. Just to confirm and rephrase your answer,  can I say that the "additional authorization" to mount is simply to provide the root password, and that therefore anyone who has access to his/her root could mount my drive (providing I've set selected the option)? Is it "yes" to both statements?

Comment: @calocedrus close enough (... technically there is no root password by default in Ubuntu, you use your own password for sudo and polkit). And users who have the privileges can mount it anyway, this option is to force users who are logged in at the system to get someone who has privileges to approve this (might be their account, or somebody else's).

Comment: @muru how can I edit the authorizations with polkit? In my case adding the `x-udisks-auth` just prevented me of making any modification in the partition.